# Remote hooks in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

In loopback i am using `afterRemote` hook for get request as follows

```
Modelname.afterRemote("**", function(ctx, expenses, next){
  if(ctx.method.name == 'find') {
      for(var i=0; i<ctx.result.length; i++){
        delete ctx.result[i].category;
      }
  }
});
```

In the above i am trying to delete a key from get Request response before sending to client. But still that appears. SO its not possible to delete a key which we have created in model.json?. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `result.unsetAttribute('field')`

```
Modelname.afterRemote("**", function(ctx, expenses, next){
  if(ctx.method.name == 'find') {
    for(var i = 0; i < ctx.result.length; i++) {
      ctx.result[i].unsetAttribute('category');
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a [related GitHub issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/162), in case you are interested.

It is documented in the [Operation hooks](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks#Operationhooks-beforesave) section of a LoopBack documentation, but there is sadly no mention of it in the [Remote hooks](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+hooks) section.

Note: If you want to restrict this hook to only *find* method, you can specify it with `Modelname.afterRemote("find", function (ctx, expenses, next) {});`.